# not able to see preview of projects

Tags: overleaf

I'm using overleaf online. I have my own zip file which I have uploaded on overleaf. But I am not able to see the source code or preview. It is showing as 'sorry, no preview is available'. Even I tried to get the preview of my older projects but again it is showing up the same 'Sorry, no preview is available'. How can i see the preview of my projects?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you asked the support of overleaf? Did you unpack your zip file?

Comment: The preview tag is for a specific package in TeX (the tag description can help explain that).  If it's about Overleaf, you can use the Overleaf tag (and Overleaf support is pretty active in following this site).  But they'll probably tell you to contact Overleaf support, so that you can give them the project id and they can look at your specific project.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) Like Teepeemm said, best to send us your project's URL at support@overleaf.com so we can take a closer look at your files. But if you're trying to open .pdf files that are included in the source files area of your project, these can't currently be viewed on Overleaf, unfortunately. Only the output PDF of the .tex file you compile in Overleaf can be previewed. And .tex files are only detected as such if they have a .tex extension in their name. So if you're seeing "sorry, no preview is available" for source code, I suspect that the file extension is missing.

Comment: Do you have any news for us?